# Error while trying to follow tutorial

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm currently learning how to use ROS, but while I was following the tutorials in part 3 of the tutorial, I encountered an error. I was at the part where I try to edit:
The beginner_tutorials
When I try to change what's inside of the <> I get this error:
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
The same thing happens when I try do edit anything in the <> in the next few part of the tutorials.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88936/error-while-trying-to-follow-tutorial./) by [gishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/7566/gishi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-10-08**:
might help if you can post a short example of your edits

**Comment by [gishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/7566/gishi/) on 2013-10-09**:
Well in the tutorial it said i could change it to anythine i wanted. So i just changed it to test instead of deacription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot change the tags in the XML file: i.e., what's inside the <> angle brackets. Rather, you can change what's between the two tags, i.e., you can write

ABCDEF 
or something else. But the tags themselves are predefined and when this xml file is read, the system looks for what's between the description tags. So changing the tag itself will result in the system not understanding what you are specifying.

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/7566/gishi/) on 2013-10-09**:
Ah, that makes a lot more sense.
Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of writing < description >The beginner_tutorials package in the command prompt, write

gedit package.xml

A window with the package.xml file will open up. In this new window you can edit the description and everything else. Then click save. Then go back to command prompt and type

cat package.xml

Now you can see your changes.

Good luck!

Aaron

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Y](https://answers.ros.org/users/13111/aaron-y/) with karma: 21 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dovulthesloth](https://answers.ros.org/users/37340/dovulthesloth/) on 2018-09-05**:
U'r de real mvp maan